# Camel: how to aggregate files based on exchange in pattern

Tags: apache-camel

I have a class to run my route; The input comes from a queue (which is filled by a route that does a query and inserts the rows as messages on the queue)

These messages each contain a few headers:
- pdu_id, basically a prefetch on the filename.
- pad: the path the files reside in

What is to happen: I want the files in the path named by their "pdu_id".* in a tar; After that a REST call  is to be done to remove the documents source.

I know a route has a from; but basically I need a route with a dynamic "from", and as below code example shows, queueing froms doesn't do the trick.

The question is what to use instead; I could not find a similar thing, but it can be I didn't use the right google search; in which case I'm deeply sorry.

```
public class ToDeleteTarAndDeleteRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception 
    {
        from("broker1:todelete.message_ids.queue")
        .from("file:///?fileName=${in.header.pad}${in.header.pdu_id}.*")
        .aggregate(new TarAggregationStrategy())
        .constant(true)
        .completionFromBatchConsumer()
        .eagerCheckCompletion()
        .to("file:///?fileName=${in.header.pad}${in.header.pdu_id}.tar")
        .log("${header.pdu_id} tarred")
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("DELETE"))
        .setHeader("Connection", constant("Close"))
        .enrich()
        .simple("http:127.0.0.1/restfuldb${header.pdu_id}?httpClient.authenticationPreemptive=true")
        .log("${header.pdu_id} tarred and deleted.");
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand but if all the messages end up on the same queue, why do you need a dynamic from?

Comment: Why do you have two from statements? Do you want to read from a file based on data you get from the queue?

Comment: Yes; in the directory (set in the ${header.pad}) are various files; their basename is a uuid, and there are various file extentions. Hence the ${header.pdu_id} which is a uuid. I want each ${header.pad}${header.pdu_id}.* in a tar ${header.pad}.${header.pdu_id}.tar (and have the files themselves removed after)

Comment: Got a bit closer, I think; Instead of the second "from", I stumbled upon something that made me think I should use the pollEnrich() feature. It doesn't really work yet, though:
.setHeader("fqpn", simple("file://${header.pad}?fileName=${header.pdu_id}.*")) 
...
.pollEnrich("file:///?fileName=${header.fqpn}")

Comment: quite silly; the header has a fileName; so changed that: .setHeader("fqpn", simple("${header.pad}${header.pdu_id}.*")). Still no luck, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the solution to the problem consisted of a few changes based on what @daBigBug answered.

- pollEnrich's simple expression uses antInclude rather than fileName;
- aggregate is put after pollenrich; as each batch is the set of files, rather than the input from the queue. The input from the queue only provides meta information based on which actions are to be taken.
- aggregationStrategy() is not possible in a RouteBuilder; I used aggregate() instead.

I removed the unmarshal(); I don't see why this would be needed; the files can contain binary content.

```
from("broker1:todelete.message_ids.queue")
.pollEnrich()
  .simple("file:${in.header.pad}?antInclude=${in.header.pdu_id}.*")
.aggregate(new TarAggregationStrategy())
    .constant(true)
    .completionFromBatchConsumer()
    .eagerCheckCompletion()
.log("tarring to: ${header.pad}${header.pdu_id}.tar")
.setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, simple("${header.pdu_id}.tar"))
.setHeader(Exchange.FILE_PATH, simple("${header.pad}"))
.to("file://ignored")
...(and the rest of the operations);
```

I now see the files are getting picked up and even placed in a tar; however, the filename of the tar is unexpected as is the location (it's placed in ./ignored); Also in the rest of the operation, it appears the exchange headers are lost.

If anyone can help figure out how to preserve the headers in a safe way... I'm much obliged. Should I use a new question for that, or should I rephrase the question.

Comment: upon closer inspection of the tar files, I noticed the files included in the tar do not have the same pattern. I expect files  e.g. A.1 A.2 and A.3, but instead see A.1,B.2 and C.2; the cause might be that more than one message is processed at a time...

Comment: To preserve the headers, you can either put them in exchange properties, OR store them in the newExchange headers in your aggregation strategy

Comment: Going to accept this answer and starting a new question as I see behaviour I am not expecting. This is better addressed in a separate question. I see more than one jms message consumed and used in the aggregation; along with the lost headers. My thanks for the help provided so far!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Poll enrich can help you in doing it. You should use it something like this:

```
from("broker1:todelete.message_ids.queue")
        .aggregationStrategy(new TarAggregationStrategy())
        .pollEnrich()
        .simple("file:///?fileName=${in.header.pad}/${in.header.pdu_id}.*")
        .unmarshal().string()
        .to("file:///?fileName=${in.header.pad}/${in.header.pdu_id}.tar")
        .log("${header.pdu_id} tarred")
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("DELETE"))
        .setHeader("Connection", constant("Close"))
        .enrich()
        .simple("http:127.0.0.1/restfuldb${header.pdu_id}?httpClient.authenticationPreemptive=true")
        .log("${header.pdu_id} tarred and deleted.");
```

Comment: Indeed getting closer; the .aggregationStrategy(new TarAggregationStrategy()) as not allowed, but I have the pollEnrich working. I put the aggregation _after_ the pollEnrich() however; Now my challenge has changed; After the aggregation I no longer have my headers... Need to find a workaround for that.